# Hbase data deleted after restart

Tags: database, hadoop, hbase

I just started with hbase. Therefore I created a table and filled this
table with some data. But after restarting my computer all the data
has gone. This even happens when stopping hbase with stop-hbase.sh.
hbase installation : pseudo distributed 
hbase-site.xml :

hbase.rootdir 
hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase

Comment: hbase installation : pseudo distributed 
hbase-site.xml :
 
 <name>hbase.rootdir</name> 
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>

Answer (score 2):

By default, hbase.rootdir is set to /tmp/hbase-${user.name}, which could mean you lose all your data whenever your server or test machine reboots because a lot of operating systems (OSes) clear out /tmp during a restart.

Source: Hbase the definitive guide - 2 nd edition.

If you are saving your hbase files in local dir, then add below properties in your hbase-site.xml.

```
    <property>
      <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
      <value>file:///<PATH>/hbase</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
      <value>file:///<PATH>/zookeeper</value>
    </property>
```

Comment: this is what i found in hbase-site.xml file: <property>
      <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
      <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
    </property>

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
      <value>file:///Users/yadav.hariom/local_tool_setup/hbase-2.2.3/hbase_my_data/rootdir</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
      <value>/Users/yadav.hariom/local_tool_setup/hbase-2.2.3/hbase_my_data/datadir</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

this is working for me : https://sparkbyexamples.com/hbase/setup-run-hbase-standalone-mode/